# How to get the value of a row extracted using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, html-content-extraction

I have a table and I'm retrieving each table row by doing this:

```
$(function(){
        $('table tr').click(function(){
            var $row = $(this).html();
            alert($row);
        });
    });
```

This gets me the current row like this:

```
<td>2</td>
<td>Malcriado</td>
<td>Bota</td>
<td>Tipo2</td>
<td>NuevaDesc</td>
<td>NuevaDesc</td>
<td></td>
<td>Cerdo</td>
<td>Azul</td>
<td>oso</td>
<td>Rojo</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>metal</td>
<td>sss</td>
<td></td>
<td>Delicias</td>
```

What I am trying to accomplish next is to remove the td's and get the values in between and get them into an array, but I haven't been able to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`children()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method to get the `<td>` elements, then the [`map()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to create an Object containing the values, and finally the [`toArray()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) method to convert it into an Array.

```
$('table tr').click(function(){
    var values = $(this).children('td').map(function() {
        return this.innerHTML;
    }).toArray();

    alert(values);
});
```

Comment: yeah this is very nice, i just would use innerText instead of innerHtml +1

Comment: @aSeptik: That's a valid point, but since there's no actual markup, the result will be the same, and with `innerText` you'll need to add `|| textContent` for cross-browser support. :o)

Comment: so, just thank's for sharing...! LoL as always you are great. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> - **DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ureqa4/3

```
$(function() {
    $('table tr').click(function() {
        var arr = [];
        $('td', this).each(function(i, item) {
            if (item.innerHTML) 
              arr.push(item.innerHTML);
        });
        alert(arr.join(','));
    });
});
```

*jast for sake added check for empty `<TD>`*

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the  elements in the row and get their text:

```
var contentArray = [];
$("td", $row).each(function(){
  contentArray.push($(this).text());
});
```